# how to check a password's Content and length using an array Functions

Tags: php, regex

A user enters a password, say `'tomorrow1234'`.  I'm aware that I can split it into an array with `str_split`, but after that, I want to go through each value and search them for things such as capitalization, number, or white space.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old standby function I use to valiate password complexity. It requires that the password contains upper and lowercase letters, as well as non-alpha characters. Length checks are trivial and are handled elsewhere.

```
$req_regex = array(
    '/[A-Z]/',      //uppercase
    '/[a-z]/',      //lowercase
    '/[^A-Za-z]/'   //non-alpha
);

foreach($req_regex as $regex) {
    if( !preg_match($regex, $password) ) {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I use the array and a loop so it's easy to add/remove conditions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your trying to verify password strength.

Check out this web page, your solution would be pretty complex to write a specific answer for, but you can use regex to check for things like capitalization, symbols and digits. This page has several examples you could modify for your needs.

http://www.cafewebmaster.com/check-password-strength-safety-php-and-regex

This is what I would use:

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Checks for 1 letter, 1 number, 1 special character and at least 8 characters long.